# Error compiling a Codename One project

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying to build a project that I have not build in over a year.  I have the latest codename one plugin, get the following errors:

> error: package java.util.logging does not exist
>          [javac] import java.util.logging.Level;
>
> error: cannot find symbol
>          [javac] import java.io.BufferedInputStream;

Any idea on how to get this compiling again?  I'm using eclipse neon

Just realized these `extensions` are being compiled with javase instead of android. `lib/impl/native/javase`. I'm performing a `send android build`, is there a setting for this that I need to add?

```
Buildfile: /Users/sam/dev/wordtime5/codeone/codename1/build.xml

jar:
        [echo] Compile is forcing compliance to the supported API's/features for maximum device compatibility. This allows smaller
        [echo]          code size and wider device support
        [copy] Copying 19 files to /Users/sam/dev/wordtime5/codeone/codename1/build/tmp
        [copy] Copying 37 files to /Users/sam/dev/wordtime5/codeone/codename1/build/tmp
       [javac] /Users/sam/dev/wordtime5/codeone/codename1/build.xml:147: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
       [javac] Compiling 101 source files to /Users/sam/dev/wordtime5/codeone/codename1/build/tmp
       [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
       [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
        [copy] Copying 281 files to /Users/sam/dev/wordtime5/codeone/codename1/build/tmp
         [jar] Building jar: /Users/sam/dev/wordtime5/codeone/codename1/dist/CN1WordTime5.jar
       [javac] /Users/sam/dev/wordtime5/codeone/codename1/build.xml:171: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
       [javac] Compiling 32 source files to /Users/sam/dev/wordtime5/codeone/codename1/native/internal_tmp
       [javac] /Users/sam/dev/wordtime5/codeone/codename1/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/admob/AdMobNativeImpl.java:16: error: package java.util.logging does not exist
       [javac] import java.util.logging.Level;
       [javac]                         ^
       [javac] /Users/sam/dev/wordtime5/codeone/codename1/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/admob/AdMobNativeImpl.java:17: error: package java.util.logging does not exist
       [javac] import java.util.logging.Logger;
       [javac]                         ^
       [javac] /Users/sam/dev/wordtime5/codeone/codename1/lib/impl/native/javase/com/neovisionaries/ws/client/WebSocket.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
       [javac] import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
       [javac]               ^
       [javac]   symbol:   class BufferedInputStream
       [javac]   location: package java.io
       [javac] /Users/sam/dev/wordtime5/codeone/codename1/lib/impl/native/javase/com/neovisionaries/ws/client/WebSocket.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
       [javac] import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
       [javac]               ^
       [javac]   symbol:   class BufferedOutputStream
       [javac]   location: package java.io
       [javac] /Users/sam/dev/wordtime5/codeone/codename1/lib/impl/native/javase/com/neovisionaries/ws/client/WebSocket.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
       [javac] import java.net.Socket;
       [javac]                ^
       [javac]   symbol:   class Socket
       [javac]   location: package java.net
```

Comment: Just realized these "extensions" are being compiled with javase instead of android.   "lib/impl/native/javase".   I'm performing a "send android build".  Is there a setting for this I need to add?

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when you use auto try-catch for exceptions, it adds java Logger automatically.

Do a project search for `Logger`, and remove all its Usage (Including it's `import`).

`Logger` is not supported in Codename One as CN1 has it's own `Logger` which is `com.codename1.io.Log`

Comment: Hi Diamond, this is actually in extensions.  I updated them and added a comment to my question.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to post the full StackTrace then?

Comment: I've updated the `AdmobFullScreen.cn1lib`, it will be ready soon once approved by Shai or Chen. Once ready, go to `CN1 Extensions` and update `Admob FullScreen Ads`.

Comment: Thanks, I created another question thats more on topic,  I also get the errors on the websocket code as well.

Comment: Since these compilation errors are from the JavaSE code this is probably not the right direction. Notice the use of sockets as well...